# Get relation data when search in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6

i have laravel 5.6 project
this is my model code

```
public function getClassTreaner()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'class_treaner');
}

public static function searchScoop($keyword)
{
    $data = Classe::where('id','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhere('class_name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->limit(30)
        ->get();

    return $data;
}
```

Now when I use `Searchscoop` in js code it looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: path+'classsearch',
  data: {data:this.message},
  success:(data) => {
    if(data.length >= 1)
    {
      for(i = 0;i<data.length;i++)
      {
        this.arrayresults.push({id:data[i]['id'],class_name:data[i]['class_name'],class_start_time:data[i]['class_start_time'],class_end_time:data[i]['class_end_time'],class_date:data[i]['class_date'],class_treaner:data[i]['get_class_treaner']})
      }
      this.ok = true;
    }
    else
    {
      this.ok = false;
      this.noresult = true;
    }
   },
  error:function()
  {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

In this line:

```
this.arrayresults.push({id:data[i]['id'],class_name:data[i]['class_name'],class_start_time:data[i]['class_start_time'],class_end_time:data[i]['class_end_time'],class_date:data[i]['class_date'],class_treaner:data[i]['get_class_treaner']})
```

The last result `get_class_treaner` I can't access the model relation view ajax.

I tried to write the name `getClassTreaner`, but I can't access the model data in ajax.

Comment: In success function of ajax try to console.log the data (response) and see what you get from the backend.And post it to see what is going wrong

Comment: blank data nothing

Comment: So the problem is from your backend.In laravel replace the return $data to this: return response->json($data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access a relation in your frontend, if you load it in the backend:

```
$data = Classe::where('id','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orWhere('class_name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->limit(30)
    ->with('getClassTreaner')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You wrote that `data` is empty.